# How to write multiple messages in one protobuf file?

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

Take the google's tutorial for examples:

```
message Person {
  required string name = 1;
  required int32 id = 2;
  optional string email = 3;

  enum PhoneType {
    MOBILE = 0;
    HOME = 1;
    WORK = 2;
  }

  message PhoneNumber {
    required string number = 1;
    optional PhoneType type = 2 [default = HOME];
  }

  repeated PhoneNumber phone = 4;
}

message AddressBook {
  repeated Person person = 1;
}
```

It uses an AddressBook wrapper message as storing multiple Person messages. If I serialize or deserialize it I use methods like  `AddressBook.mergeFrom(FileInputStream)` `addressBook.build.().writeTo()`

but it will obviously overflow if I have 20 million Person records. And also google says if I want to store multiple messages in one file without using the wrapper message I need to record each message's length, which is not possible for string types.

Is there a good way to serialize a large amount of messages in one file?
And I am using Java by the way.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tried this, but I'd expect it to work:

Writing:

```
CodedOutputStream output = CodedOutputStream.newInstance(...);

while (...) {
    Person person = ...;
    output.writeMessageNoTag(person);
}
```

Reading:

```
CodedInputStream input = CodedInputStream.newInstance(...);
while (!input.isAtEnd()) {
    Person.Builder builder = Person.newBuilder();
    input.readMessage(builder, null); // Or specify extension registry
    Person person = builder.build();
    // Use person
}
```

Comment: This is not helping since it is overwriting the file contents everytime and there is only one record stored at any time.

Comment: @Gopinath: You can append to the file instead of writing a new file - that's just a matter of the stream you pass into `CodedOutputStream.newInstance`. (And there will be more than one record in the file if you have more than one record to write, which is why I've got the `while` loop there.)

Answer (score 2):

The key is to open the file in append mode.

```
FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file, true);
```

So, the following will be the complete solution.

```
// writing
List<Person> addressBook = ...; // list of person to be stored
try(FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(path, true)) {
  for (Person person: addressBook) {
    person.writeDelimitedTo(output); 
  }
}

// reading
try (FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(path)) {
  while (true) {
    Person person = Person.parseDelimitedFrom(input);
    if (person == null) { // parseDelimitedFrom returns null on EOF
      break;
    }

    // use person
  }
}
```

Hope this saves somebody a few hours of time.

Answer (score 0):

In Java you can use `writeDelimitedTo` and `parseDelimitedFrom` methods for writing and reading multiple messages of the same type.

From [MessageLite documentation](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/MessageLite#writeDelimitedTo-java.io.OutputStream-):

> Like `writeTo(OutputStream)`, but writes the size of the message as a varint before writing the data. This allows more data to be written to the stream after the message without the need to delimit the message data yourself. Use `MessageLite.Builder.mergeDelimitedFrom(InputStream)` (or the static method `YourMessageType.parseDelimitedFrom(InputStream)`) to parse messages written by this method.

Example:

```
// writing
List<Person> addressBook = ...; // list of person to be stored
try(FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(path)) {
  for (Person person: addressBook) {
    person.writeDelimitedTo(output); 
  }
}

// reading
try (FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(path)) {
  while (true) {
    Person person = Person.parseDelimitedFrom(input);
    if (person == null) { // parseDelimitedFrom returns null on EOF
      break;
    }

    // use person
  }
}
```